# access the original implementation of a method from a class inheriting an abstract method

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class BaseConcrete
 {
   public virtual void DoSomething()
   {
    // Original implementation.
   }
 }

public abstract class BaseAbstract: BaseConcrete
 {
   public abstract override void DoSomething();
 }

public class SubConcrete: BaseAbstract
 {
   public override void DoSomething()
   {
    // New implementation.
   }
 }
```

How do I access the original `DoSomething()` method implementation of `BaseConcrete` class? a  `base` call does not work here in this case. Any other approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `public class SubConcrete:BaseConcrete` is the way to achieve what you need, followed by `base.DoSomething()` But is there something that prevents you from doing that?

Comment: Just being curious if this is really possible without doing SubConcrete:BaseConcrete

Comment: you can create an instance of base concrete and wrap that object within SubConcrete. This way you can access BaseConcrete implementation. But this is not the right way, because it will be misleading

Comment: My question is why doesn't the base.DoSomething() call does'nt go up in the inheritance tree upto the BaseConcrete and invoke it? (As it would happen in case of BaseAbstract being a concrete class and it skips overriding DoSomething).

Comment: `SubConcrete` does not have `BaseConcrete` in its inheritance tree,unless it is put.

Comment: At this case you should change `BaseAbstract` : `public override void DoSomething() { base.DoSomething(); }`

Comment: @CarbineCoder do you mean using an abstract class in between breaks the inheritance chain?

Comment: @izengod LOL I am totally sorry. I missed `BaseAbstract:BaseConcrete`.

Comment: You can do as  @SlavaUtesinov mentioned. It will work.Sorry for the confusion :D

Comment: I can't think of a clean way of doing this in C#. In IL you could put a `call` in (instead of a `callvirt`) that specifically accesses the target method.

Comment: @CarbineCoder hmmmm that is one thing.. but if you look closely, calling base.DoSomething() inside the BaseAbstract.DoSomething() is actually implementing the DoSomething() and it no more remains abstract.

Comment: Actually, this looks like a design flaw to me. Is there a special reason for this construction?